# Using @Url.Action in JS-asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that I have been creating and I publish it in the IIS, there everything is fine, I can visualize my Crystal Reports reports.

Now I have re-published the project (update in IIS), but I can not see my Crystal Reports reports that I call from js.

```
var url = "/ReporteIngresoVP/RPVistaPreviaIngreso";
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

At the time of calling it, it opens a new tab (as it should be) and shows me a 404:

[image]

When I open another report (from the controller) it shows me the correct `path`(everything from IIS):

[image]

As I read out there if I need to use urls that point to asp.net MVC elements from js, they should go with the `@Url.Action` so I am trying the following:

```
var url2='@Url.Action("RPVistaPreviaIngreso","CustomerReporteIngresoVP")';
window.open(url2, "_blank");
```

But when I navigate, I get the URL in this way:

[image]

How can I complete the route or can I go to the view/controller what I want in both case, Visual Studio and the project published using javascript?

**UPDATE**

I try to navigate from a click function, I never pass any url, what can I modify?

```
$('.vpBTN').click(function () {

        //OTHER DATA
        $.ajax({
            url: "setDatosIngreso",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                factura: datoFactura,
                poliza: datosPoliza,
                fecha: datosFecha,
                via: datosVia,
                bruto: datosBruto,
                neto: datosNeto,
                bultos: datosBultos
            },
            async: false,
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta) {
                var url = "IKOR/ReporteIngresoVP/RPVistaPreviaIngreso";
                window.open(url2, "_blank"); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is that JS code stored in external file? Sounds like the `Url.Action` helper is not parsed there. Note that you cannot use Razor helpers inside external script file, you need to pass it as function parameter.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes, it's an external file

Comment: How you're calling the function containing `window.open`? Can you provide some details so that I can answer by using function parameter to pass the helper result? As mentioned before, you cannot do that unless the URL is passed as parameter first.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto all the action starts from a click function, I do some things and when those things are finished I try to navigate to a controller / view, the last part is a `ajax`, I edit the question to include this

Comment: Is that AJAX call stored inside external JS too? If it's true, I suggest to move out the click trigger into Razor `<script>` tag and then call the function which contains AJAX together with passed URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to solve it and can help someone:

Create a `div` that has nothing, just with a `clas`s and `data-request-ur`l in this last I send my `@Url.Action()`

```
<div class="urlPasar" data-request-url="@Url.Action("RPVistaPreviaIngreso","ReporteIngresoVP")"></div>
```

In JS capture the value of the `data` that is in the `div`

```
var url = $('.urlPasar').data('request-url');
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Works for both in Visual Studio and in a published project

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using external JS file which included inside Razor view, and obviously you cannot use Razor HTML helpers to render complete URL inside JS file. You need to pass the URL as JS function parameter instead:

**External JS**

```
// create this function to redirect
function redirectToUrl(url)
{
    window.open(url, "_blank"); 
}
```

**Razor view (`<script>` tag)**

```
$('.vpBTN').click(function () {
    // other data

    $.ajax({
       url: "setDatosIngreso",
       method: "POST",
       data: {
           factura: datoFactura,
           poliza: datosPoliza,
           fecha: datosFecha,
           via: datosVia,
           bruto: datosBruto,
           neto: datosNeto,
           bultos: datosBultos
       },
       success: function (respuesta) {
           var url = '@Url.Action("RPVistaPreviaIngreso","CustomerReporteIngresoVP")';
           redirectToUrl(url); 
       }
   });
});
```